# RESETSEQ channel parameter

Tags: ibm-mq, reset

On my channel display i have a paramter RESETSEQ(1217) so each time the channel stop and start the sequence is set to 1217 causing all sorts of sequence errors.
Review of documentation indicates that the RESETSEQ is for a pending sequence reset.  A value of 0 (zero) indicates that there is no pending sequence reset.  So far so good...BUT I have not been able to find anything that indicates how to set this parm to 0(zero) so that the display channel shows resetseq(no) so i am stuck reseting this RCVR channel each day.

Answer (score 2):

When a reset command is issued from a sender channel, it tells the receiver what message number to set as the sequence number.  When you reset from the receiver, it doesn't have the same effect of making a change to the sender.  It seems your sender at some point was trying to send messages as seqno (1217) and that  command is still considered outstanding.  Since that time, the sender time may have recycled and that number appears to no longer be valid (explaining why you now need to set it to zero).

Do you have access to the sender channel?  If a new command were sent from the sender to reset the channel, I would expect this outstanding request to be overriden.  You may have to do a stop on both channel ends to clear up the problem. Refer to [this Technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21214505) should you encounter an in-doubt situation:

Comment: I have used the stop/resolve/start process onthe SDR channer to no avail.  The cannel still contains a RESETSEQ(1) on the RCVR and nothing i do seems to clear this up, so each night the SDR channel stops (due to idle) and next morning the channel restarts and i am out of seqeunce as teh SDR thinks it is on seqnum 341 (or some other value) and the RCVR is reset back to 1.
There has to be a way to stop this and get the SDR and RCVR back in sync where the RESETSEQ contains (NO) instead of a value.

Comment: I suggest you open a PMR with IBM support.  You may have a damaged channel scratchpad.